# Button with glyphicon pull-right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple button on which i am trying to add a glyphicon in order to get a fashion one.

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="form-group">            
        <button class="btn btn-primary form-control">
          Test
          <span class="pull-right">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">
            </span>
          </span>
        </button>            
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While it's working perfectly on chrome and safari, the glyphicon is badly positionned on mozilla. Is there a well known-issue or am I doing something wrong with the bootstrap css ?

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E0tv79VHaJLucjYz7bmz?p=preview) if you want to see exactly what I am trying to get ( on chrome ) , and what is wrong (on mozilla).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please try below code you have to add one inline property **white-space: inherit ! important;** to button

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="form-group">            
    <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" style="white-space: inherit ! important;">
      Test
      <span class="pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">
        </span>
      </span>
    </button>            
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Looks like it's working fine. My question is why this is not by default in the bootstrap css something like ’.btn{white-space: inherit ! important }’ ? Could it break something ?

Comment: Please don't edit Bootstrap css create your own class name as btn-right-icon add .btn-right-icon{white-space: inherit ! important; } and apply to that button so do not worry about breaking something in bootstrap